# How can I add the JQuery UI CSS to a Rails App

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I've added the JS files successfully, and the autocomplete widget that I am trying to use is functioning, but the CSS is not being included, so the autocomplete widget has no style. How can I add the jQuery UI CSS to my app?

I am using Rails 4 and Ruby 2 and the 'jquery-rails', '2.2.1' gem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

use stylesheet_include_tag 'css-file' name in the view. and if you need it through out the application then put it in the application.css file

```
*= file_name
```

before 
`*= require_tree` .
 make sure the css file exists in the css folder or if it is in some other place please provide the path of the file.